# Importing/Conditioning a file.txt with a "kind" of json structure in R

Tags: json, r, import

I wanted to import a .txt file in R but the format is really special and it's looks like a json format but I don't know how to import it. There is an example of my data:

```
{"datetime":"2015-07-08 09:10:00","subject":"MMM","sscore":"-0.2280","smean":"0.2593","svscore":"-0.2795","sdispersion":"0.375","svolume":"8","sbuzz":"0.6026","lastclose":"155.430000000","companyname":"3M Company"},{"datetime":"2015-07-07 09:10:00","subject":"MMM","sscore":"0.2977","smean":"0.2713","svscore":"-0.7436","sdispersion":"0.400","svolume":"5","sbuzz":"0.4895","lastclose":"155.080000000","companyname":"3M Company"},{"datetime":"2015-07-06 09:10:00","subject":"MMM","sscore":"-1.0057","smean":"0.2579","svscore":"-1.3796","sdispersion":"1.000","svolume":"1","sbuzz":"0.4531","lastclose":"155.380000000","companyname":"3M Company"}
```

To deal with this is used this code:

```
    test1 <- read.csv("C:/Users/test1.txt", header=FALSE) 

    ## Import as 5 observations (5th is all empty) of 1700 variables 
#(in fact 40 observations of 11 variables). In fact when I imported the 
#.txt file, it's having one line (5th obs) empty, and 4 lines of data and 
#placed next to each other 4 lines of data of 11 variables.

    # Get the different lines
    part1=test1[1:10]
    part2=test1[11:20]
    part3=test1[21:30]
    part4=test1[31:40]
    ...

    ## Remove the empty line (there were an empty line after each)
    part1=part1[-5,]
    part2=part2[-5,]
    part3=part3[-5,]
    ...

    ## Rename the columns
    names(part1)=c("Date Time","Subject","Sscore","Smean","Svscore","Sdispersion","Svolume","Sbuzz","Last close","Company name")
    names(part2)=c("Date Time","Subject","Sscore","Smean","Svscore","Sdispersion","Svolume","Sbuzz","Last close","Company name")
    names(part3)=c("Date Time","Subject","Sscore","Smean","Svscore","Sdispersion","Svolume","Sbuzz","Last close","Company name")
    ...

    ## Assemble data to have one dataset
    data=rbind(part1,part2,part3,part4,part5,part6,part7,part8,part9,part10)

    ## Formate Date Time
    times <- as.POSIXct(data$`Date Time`, format='{datetime:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    data$`Date Time` <- times

    ## Keep only the Date
    data$Date <- as.Date(times)

    ## Formate data - Remove text
    data$Subject <- gsub("subject:", "", data$Subject)    
    data$Sscore <- gsub("sscore:", "", data$Sscore)
    ...
```

So My code is working to reinstate the data but it's maybe very difficult and more long I know there is better ways to do it, so if you could help me with that I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many packages that read JSON, e.g. `rjson`, `jsonlite`, `RJSONIO` (they will turn in up a google search) - just pick one and give it a go.

e.g.

```
library(jsonlite)
json.text <- '{"datetime":"2015-07-08 09:10:00","subject":"MMM","sscore":"-0.2280","smean":"0.2593","svscore":"-0.2795","sdispersion":"0.375","svolume":"8","sbuzz":"0.6026","lastclose":"155.430000000","companyname":"3M Company"},{"datetime":"2015-07-07 09:10:00","subject":"MMM","sscore":"0.2977","smean":"0.2713","svscore":"-0.7436","sdispersion":"0.400","svolume":"5","sbuzz":"0.4895","lastclose":"155.080000000","companyname":"3M Company"},{"datetime":"2015-07-06 09:10:00","subject":"MMM","sscore":"-1.0057","smean":"0.2579","svscore":"-1.3796","sdispersion":"1.000","svolume":"1","sbuzz":"0.4531","lastclose":"155.380000000","companyname":"3M Company"}'

x <- fromJSON(paste0('[', json.text, ']'))
             datetime subject  sscore  smean svscore sdispersion svolume  sbuzz     lastclose companyname
1 2015-07-08 09:10:00     MMM -0.2280 0.2593 -0.2795       0.375       8 0.6026 155.430000000  3M Company
2 2015-07-07 09:10:00     MMM  0.2977 0.2713 -0.7436       0.400       5 0.4895 155.080000000  3M Company
3 2015-07-06 09:10:00     MMM -1.0057 0.2579 -1.3796       1.000       1 0.4531 155.380000000  3M Company
```

I paste the '[' and ']' around your JSON because you have multiple JSON elements (the rows in the dataframe above) and for this to be well-formed JSON it needs to be an array, i.e. `[ {...}, {...}, {...} ]` rather than `{...}, {...}, {...}`.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation ! But it worked with the data sample I put in the question, but not with my all dataset... I will edit my question with my all dataset. I don't know why but I have this error (but I don't find any "{"d" in my dataset... : Error in parse_string(txt, bigint_as_char) : 
  lexical error: invalid character inside string.
          companyname":"3M Company"},{"d {"datetime":"2015-07-08 09:10
                     (right here) ------^

Comment: I succed this way:

library(jsonlite)
json.text <- read.table("C:/Users/test1.txt")
x <- fromJSON(paste0('[', json.text, ']'))
View(x)

But I am supposed to have 40 lines and only have 10...

> json.text <- read.table("C:/Users/test1.txt")
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 2 did not have 341 elements
In addition: Warning message:
In read.table("C:/Users/test1.txt") :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'C:/Users/test1.txt'

Comment: I can't help you as I can't get access to your data, but it looks like your JSON is malformed, as opposed to an R problem. You will have to examine your JSON (e.g. run it through a validator) to see if it is OK.

Comment: I found my problem: There was an "enter"/space in my dataset... Thank you for your help